# How to stop hover to set value of typeahead input using Bootstrap typeaheads plugin Typeahead.js?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application using the [bootstrap typeahead plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead).

I have a typeahead looking like the following:

[image]

Here the items are not selected until I click. However, lets say that I hover down the list without a click:

[image]

But when I move the mouse outside the form, the hovered item now turns selected:

[image]

Which then means if I click anywhere on the site, the `val()` on the typeahead becomes the before hovered item.

How do I make sure that the `val()` is only set, if I click the item in the typeaheadlist?

I have already set the `autoSelect: false` settings, which solves the problem if I have not yet hovered (by default first item is selected).

Comment: Post the code, or a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that I have for you is edit the plugin. Is not hard at all

1. Download the plugin from the repository [bootstrap3-typeahead.js](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.js)
2. Go to the line 575 and comment that line.

> ```
> blur: function (e) {
>       if (!this.mousedover && !this.mouseddown && this.shown) {
>         //this.select();
>         this.hide();
>         this.focused = false;
>         this.keyPressed = false;
>       } else if (this.mouseddown) {
>         // This is for IE that blurs the input when user clicks on scroll.
>         // We set the focus back on the input and prevent the lookup to occur again
>         this.skipShowHintOnFocus = true;
>         this.$element.focus();
>         this.mouseddown = false;
>       } 
> },
> ```

3. Replace the code :)

And that should works! works for me ;)

Comment: Damn! I didn't even think of that, and it obviously worked perfect. I can award the bounty in 1 hour.

(Not sure why the question got a downvote - anyway - you managed to solved the problem and deserve the bounty ;-) )

Comment: I had the typeahead included in the file bootstrap.js (downloaded as a bundle). Your tip helped me avoid the typeahead hiding on mouseover. So this is a related problem perhaps.  Observed in Boostrap 2.3.1